# Is there a function to get specific number values associated with the names in my list?

Tags: python, list, function

```
birthdays = [
    ('Bobby White', '08/06/2003'),
    ('George Washington', '02/22/1732'),
    ('Kim Kardashian', '10/21/1980')

def age():
    global birthdays
    name = birthdays[0]
    dateList = (name[1].split("/"))         
    aDay = int(dateList[0])
    aMonth = int(dateList[1])
    aYear = int(dateList[2])
    print(birthdays)
    Person = input("Who's age do you want to find?(Input their exact name)")
    for item in birthdays:
        if item == Person:
            aYear
            AgeCalc = 2022 - aYear
            print(Person, "is/will be", AgeCalc, "this year.")
```

I want to pull the year located in my list for any item in it so i can subtract the year by the current year to find their age. I'm somewhat new to using Python and couldn't find a function to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need `global` if you're only reading the variable. It's only needed if you assign to the variable.

Comment: `aYear` is the year of the first person in the list, not the person that matches `Person`. And you need `if item[0] == Person:`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the year of the person that matches `Person`, not the first person in the `birthdays` list.

```
def age():
    Person = input("Who's age do you want to find?(Input their exact name)")
    for name, birthday in birthdays:
        if name == Person:
            aDay, aMonth, aYear = map(int, birthday.split('/'))
            AgeCalc = 2022 - aYear
            print(Person, "is/will be", AgeCalc, "this year.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a Dictionary instead of going over a list?
It's much more "pythonic" and efficient.

something like:

```
birthdays = 
    { 'Bobby White': '08/06/2003',
    'George Washington': '02/22/1732',
    'Kim Kardashian': '10/21/1980' }

Person = input("Who's age do you want to find?(Input their exact name)")

print (birthdays[Person])
```